# Remove available "from" addresses on "send an email" page

Tags: email, email2case

When clicking on the "Send an Email" button on the emails related list on cases, you get the page of the same name. On this page, there is a field to select the From address.

How can you remove some email addresses from the "From" picklist?

I understand form https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_send.htm&language=en_US that the email addresses shown in the picklist are those with email2case routing. (Some email addresses are shown twice in the picklist, so I am not sure about this.) If this is true: Can you still have email2case routing for xyz@company.com without xyz@company.com showing up in the "From" picklist on the "Send an email" page? Maybe a JavaScript hack would do the trick, but I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: The points re: org-wide addresses are valid in that they show up in the "from" field when sending an email. However, email2case addresses also appear in the list, which I believe is where the original question is stemming from. These however can not be restricted (as far as I know...) if I'm wrong, please let me know as I would like to restrict them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email addresses available in from the **email address** field mostly configured in Setup -> Administration Setup -> Email Administration -> organization-wide addresses.

You can remove from that list.

Comment: More information : you can select which profil can access to this email adress (for exemple only system admin). Removing access to profiles doesn't interfere with emailToCase or workflow.

Comment: deva - I learned that the email addresses are actually the Organization-wide Addresses and the addresses for which an email2case routing exists.

Comment: Yann G. - Thank you very much. You can define access by profile on each organization-wide address.

Comment: I figured out why some addresses appear twice - your email to case addresses also appear in here.  So if you have  the same address as an OWD and an email to case address, it appears twice!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the latest response from Salesforce to the [Restrict Which Address You Can Send an Email From](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpcTAAS) idea:

> You can use the Default Handler for email action (Apex code) to
>   restrict access to FROM addresses in the case feed. For more
>   information, please see the following link:
>
> [https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm)

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the from address, do the following

1. Setup > Case > Support Settings > Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed
   Items = Y
2. Edit Page layout > Feed View > Specify From Address(es) and manually
   enter the address.

The limitation is it just displays the raw email address. I want the email to appear with display name **Customer Support** support@yourcompany.com at the recipient end, but  could not figure out how to do it. All it accepts is support@yourcompany.com

Answer (score -1):

Check your Organizational Wide Email Addresses (you can remove certain email addresses from the From: pulldown by limiting access by profile) this may help get rid of some of them.

Also, see if you have your email2case routing email address listed in the OrgWide email addresses,

Check to see who your default Case User is - and what email address that user account is using.

You can limit this pulldown to just 2 email address - 1. The logged in user and 2. The email 2 case address.

If you are using the service cloud and case feeds - you can specify the default from: address (started in Spring 14)

I understood EXACTLY what EJS was saying because I took more than 30 seconds to read and understand rather than rifle off a hostile flame